# Deno: Processing tar archive results in checksum error (Standard Library)

Tags: tar, deno

I would like to process a tar archive with help of `tar.ts` from [Standard Library](https://deno.land/std/archive/tar.ts).

The archive can be written successfully to `test.tar` by following code:

```js
import { Tar, Untar } from "https://deno.land/std/archive/tar.ts";

// create tar archive
const tar = new Tar();
const content = new TextEncoder().encode("hello tar world!");
await tar.append("output.txt", {
  reader: new Deno.Buffer(content),
  contentSize: content.byteLength,
});
await Deno.writeFile("./test.tar", tar.out);
```

However, reading the tar triggers an error:

```
error: Uncaught Error: checksum error  
      throw new Error("checksum error");  
        --------^
    at Untar.extract (https://deno.land/std/archive/tar.ts:432:13)  
    at async file:///C:/Users/bela/Desktop/script/test.ts:23:16
```

The code:

```js
// read from tar archive
const untar = new Untar(await Deno.open("./test.tar"));
const buf = new Deno.Buffer();
const result = await untar.extract(buf); // <-- this line triggers error
const untarText = new TextDecoder("utf-8").decode(buf.bytes());
```

Where did I miss a step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `tar.getReader()` to get the correct `tar` content.

```js
const tar = new Tar();
const content = new TextEncoder().encode("hello tar world!");
await tar.append("output.txt", {
    reader: new Deno.Buffer(content),
    contentSize: content.byteLength,
});

const writer = await Deno.open("./test.tar", { write: true, create: true });
await Deno.copy(tar.getReader(), writer);
```

```js
const untar = new Untar(await Deno.open("./test.tar", { read: true }));
const buf = new Deno.Buffer();
const result = await untar.extract(buf); // <-- this line triggers error
const untarText = new TextDecoder("utf-8").decode(buf.bytes());
console.log(untarText);
```

*`tar.out` is currently a zero-filled `Uint8Array` which appears to be a bug in the std code*

Comment: You're welcome. `.out` seems like a bug from porting `tar` module from another library. I'll submit a PR later on to fix it.

Comment: Now you have answered my remaining question regarding `tar.out` :-). Removing `out` seems like a good idea then, since it may be misleading and TS could not protect with type checks.

Comment: Out of curiosity: the current tar API seems to be limited to file processing (not directories), if I read the implementation correctly. Do you know, if there are plans to extend this API or is there another workaround? Just tell me, if an answer might be worth it on its own for people in future - I would be happy to post a new question.

Comment: There's no built-in way currently, but you can create a new question and I can provide an example since the functionality can be achieved.
BTW just submitted the PR to remove `.out` https://github.com/denoland/deno/pull/6185

Comment: Thanks! Question opened [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62270112/read-and-write-whole-directories-with-tar-archive-standard-library)