# Read and write whole directories with tar archive (Standard Library)

Tags: deno

This is a continuation of [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62262954/deno-processing-tar-archive-results-in-checksum-error-standard-library).

It seems to me, that current implementation of the [`std/archive/tar.ts`](https://deno.land/std/archive/tar.ts) module only allows reads and writes per file and not for whole directories.

So far, my reference source are the [test files](https://deno.land/std/archive/tar_test.ts), which only show case single file processing. But what if, for example, a directory `./my-dir/` with multiple files and a tar archive `./test.tar` is given.

How can I then utilize [`append`](https://deno.land/std/archive/tar.ts#L279), [`extract`](https://deno.land/std/archive/tar.ts#L416) & Co. to efficiently write `./my-dir/` to `./test.tar` archive and read all file contents back from it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can archive a directory by using `std/fs/walk`

```js
import { walk, walkSync } from "https://deno.land/std/fs/walk.ts";
import { Tar } from "https://deno.land/std/archive/tar.ts";

// Async
const tar = new Tar();

for await (const entry of walk("./dir-to-archive")) {
    if (!entry.isFile) {
        continue;
    }
    await tar.append(entry.path, {
        filePath: entry.path,
    });
}

const writer = await Deno.open("./out.tar", { write: true, create: true });
await Deno.copy(tar.getReader(), writer);
```

`Untar` implementation for folders/multiple files was broken, it was fixed by [this PR](https://github.com/denoland/deno/pull/6217) and currently available in master using `https://deno.land/std/archive/tar.ts`

```js
import { Untar } from "https://deno.land/std/archive/tar.ts";
import { ensureFile } from "https://deno.land/std/fs/ensure_file.ts";
import { ensureDir } from "https://deno.land/std/fs/ensure_dir.ts";

const reader = await Deno.open("./out.tar", { read: true });
const untar = new Untar(reader);

for await (const entry of untar) {
  console.log(entry); // metadata
  /*
    fileName: "archive/deno.txt",
    fileMode: 33204,
    mtime: 1591657305,
    uid: 0,
    gid: 0,
    size: 24400,
    type: 'file'
  */

  if (entry.type === "directory") {
    await ensureDir(entry.fileName);
    continue;
  }

  await ensureFile(entry.fileName);
  const file = await Deno.open(entry.fileName, { write: true });
  // <entry> is a reader
  await Deno.copy(entry, file);
}
reader.close();
```

## Update

Created a [lib](https://github.com/marcosc90/transform) to allow transformations, including gzip/gunzip to create & read `.tar.gz`

**gzip**

```js
import * as Transform from "https://deno.land/x/transform/mod.ts";
const { GzEncoder } = Transform.Transformers;

/** ... **/
const writer = await Deno.open("./out.tar.gz", { write: true, create: true });
await Transform.pipeline(tar.getReader(), new GzEncoder())
    .to(writer);

writer.close();
```

**gunzip**

```js
import * as Transform from "https://deno.land/x/transform/mod.ts";
const { GzDecoder } = Transform.Transformers;

/** ... **/
const reader = await Deno.open("./out.tar.gz", { read: true });
const untar = new Untar(
    Transform.newReader(input, new GzDecoder())
);

for await (const entry of untar) {
    console.log(entry);
}
```

Comment: @bela53 I almost have a working implementation of `Untar`, I'll submit a PR soon to deno, and I'll update once it's been fixed.

Comment: That is awesome!

Comment: @bela53 fixed in https://github.com/denoland/deno/pull/6217 and updated my answer :)

Comment: @bela53 in case you are interested updated the answer with `.tar.gz` explanation :)

Comment: Thank you very much! I would double up-vote the answer, if possible... wait there apparently has been developed a redundant thanks button (-: